# Can I specify conda directory locations with shell variables?

Tags: python, shell, conda

Using `~/.condarc` it is possible to specify custom location for environments or package cache e.g.

```
pkgs_dirs:
  - /some/path/.conda/pkgs
envs_dirs:
  - /some/path/.conda/envs
```

I would like to be able to specify these with shell variables rather than user files. Is that possible? Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conda provides a few options, which are documented in the guide, [*The Conda Configuration Engine for Power Users*](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/conda-configuration-engine-power-users).

The most relevant to the settings at hand are:

1. The values in the `~/.condarc` file can be manipulated using the `conda config` command. For example,

   ```bash
   conda config --add envs_dirs /some/other/path
   ```
2. All configuration settings can be overridden by environment variables of the form `CONDA_<CONFIG_VARIABLE>`, where `<CONFIG_VARIABLE>` is an uppercase string of the configuration variable. For the `envs_dirs` and `pkgs_dirs`, these seem to prepend to any values loaded from `.condarc`. One can check this in action with something like

   ```bash
   CONDA_ENVS_DIRS=/some/path/.conda/envs conda config --show envs_dirs
   ```

   and it will give

   ```bash
   envs_dirs:
     - /some/path/.conda/envs
     - /home/user/miniconda3/envs
   ```

   where the second entry is already in the `.condarc`. Not sure the extent to which multiple paths can be added through this mechanism though.

Comment: Thanks. This addresses my problem exactly. Somehow I missed this in the docs. If I understood correctly the delimiter is a comma as opposed to colon?

Comment: @RobertManson-Sawko oh you might be right. I had only tried colon and semicolon, and neither of those worked.